# To achieve the goal, he is willing to use anything, even friendship

Tags: vocabulary

Suppose a city is building 5G infrastructure, something like base station. There are three manufacturers selling those devices. The mayor of the city has not decided to choose which manufacturer.

Mark, the CEO of one of the manufacturers is trying to make friends with the mayor.

Obviously, making friends is not the actual aim of Mark and is just the means of selling devices to the city, which is Mark's true purpose.

Is there any adjectives (phrases) to describe Mark? To achieve the goal, he is willing to use anything, even friendship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any adjectives (phrases) to describe Mark?

Sure. There are many. Here are a few words you can use (but note that some of these are nouns).

> 1. [Hanger-on](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hanger-on): If you describe someone as a hanger-on, you are critical of them because they are trying to be friendly with a richer or more important person, especially in order to gain an advantage for themselves. (Collins)
> 2. [Manipulative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/manipulative?q=Manipulative): A manipulative person tries to control people to their advantage. (Cambridge)
> 3. [Conniving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/conniving): A conniving person deceives others for their own advantage. (Cambridge)
> 4. [Cunning](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cunning): Someone who is cunning has the ability to achieve things in a clever way, often by deceiving other people. (Collins) Also see [shrewd](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/shrewd) and [unscrupulous](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unscrupulous).
> 5. [User](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/user): a person who uses a relationship with someone only in order to get some advantage for themselves. (Cambridge)
> 6. [Opportunist](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/opportunist): If you describe someone as opportunist, you are critical of them because they take advantage of any situation in order to gain money or power, without considering whether their actions are right or wrong. (Collins)
> 7. [Self-seeking](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-seeking): interested in your own advantage in everything that you do. (Cambridge). Also [self-serving](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-serving).
> 8. [Leech](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/leech): a person who gives attention to someone over a long period in order to get their money or support. (Cambridge) Also see [parasite](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/parasite).

Basically, Mark's intention is to get that contract, as you say. He intends to manipulate this mayor to get what he wants by being his friend. I would say that for this case, the first five are quite appropriate.